# How do I segue from each collectionview cell into another viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a collectionview programmatically and I am trying to figure out how to segue from each collectionview cell to a new view controller.

I added this to my code (shown below) and it now partially works. I am only able to segue from the albumsarray to a new view controller, but not from the imagesarray.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let name = arraysOfIDs[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}
```

But it did not work.

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
   UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 16
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .clear
        return cv
    }()

    let backgrounImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "BG")
        return iv
    }()

    let imagesCellId = "imagesCellId"
    let albumsCellId = "albumsCellId"

    let imagesArray = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5"]
    let albumsArray = ["album1", "album2", "album3", "album4", "album5", "album6", "album7", "album8", "album9"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 arraysOfIDs = ["Tools", "Arts & Craft", "Baby & Kids", "Bikes", "Boats", "Books", "Cars & Trucks", "Camera & Cell Phone", "Clothes", "Electronics", "Gardening", "Furniture", "Music & Instruments", "Sports", "Toys & Gaming"]
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        collectionView.register(ImagesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: imagesCellId)
        collectionView.register(AlbumCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: albumsCellId)

        view.addSubview(backgrounImageView)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        backgrounImageView.setAnchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
        collectionView.setAnchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 1 {
            return albumsArray.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: albumsCellId, for: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
            cell.album = albumsArray[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: imagesCellId, for: indexPath) as! ImagesCell
        cell.images = imagesArray
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let name = arraysOfIDs[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 3) - 16, height: 100)
        }
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 300)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if section == 1 {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 8, bottom: 10, right: 8)
        }
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
}

class ImagesCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var images: [String]? {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 30
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .clear
        return cv
    }()

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.setAnchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        collectionView.register(IconsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! IconsCell
        if let imageName = images?[indexPath.item] {
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 200, height: frame.height - 20)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 14, bottom: 0, right: 14)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private class IconsCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        let imageView: UIImageView = {
            let iv = UIImageView()
            iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            iv.clipsToBounds = true
            iv.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            return iv
        }()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setup()
        }

        func setup() {
            setCellShadow()
            addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.setAnchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

    }

}

class AlbumCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var album: String? {
        didSet {
            if let imageName = album {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }
        }
    }

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        return iv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        setCellShadow()
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.setAnchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have AndogoViewController and NewViewController classes in storyboard?

Comment: Can you check if `navigationController` is not nil?

Comment: I added this to my code (shown below) and it now partially works. I am only able to segue from the albumsarray to a new view controller, but not from the imagesarray.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let name = arraysOfIDs[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }